# Have multiple buttons have the same function?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, swift2

I am creating an app where I need a button that generates more buttons. I have my code like this:

```
    func showButtons(array:Array<UIButton>)
{
    for(var i:Int = 0; i < array.count; i++)
    {
        array[i].setImage(UIImage(named: "StartButton.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        array[i].frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200)), CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200)), 100, 100)
        array[i].addTarget(self, action: "pressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(array[i])
    }
}
```

The pressed button is this:

```
 func pressed(sender:AnyObject?)
{
    maybe()
}
```

But I know that is not the problem because another button, which was not create programmatically and has it's own action function, uses the same function and does not crash.

My crash report is here:

> (104.0, 70.0)
>   2016-02-02 10:34:11.267 Test[5150:1087940] -[Test.ViewController pressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a8ac3be90
>   2016-02-02 10:34:11.283 Test[5150:1087940] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test.ViewController pressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a8ac3be90'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c81e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001039c1deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c8a48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101bd790a ___forwarding_** + 970
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101bd74b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x00000001024a0194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010260f6fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010260f9c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010260eaf8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010250f49b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>       10  UIKit                               0x00000001025101d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001024beb66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000102498d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
>       13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101bada31 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ba395c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ba2e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ba2828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106297ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       18  UIKit                               0x000000010249e610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       19  Test                                0x0000000101aa134d main + 109
>       20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001044ca92d start + 1
>       21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

I believe my problem is I have all of e buttons attached to the action "pressed" so it sends a crash. Does anyone know a way to fix this/replace this. I have looked at the posts showing how to programmatically make a UIButton in Swift.

Comment: what is your pressed function? what is your crash?

Comment: My pressed functions is definitely not the problem because it just calls another function, and I have a different button that calls that function and no crash.

Comment: Please post it anyways, along with the crash message you are seeing. The issue could be how you are adding the target to the buttons.

Comment: Okay hold on for a second...

Comment: Did the button "pressed" have any params?  if that you should add "pressed:" instead of "pressed" in the action param.

Comment: It takes an AnyObject for the sole reason that the other buttons have a default of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to God (or Latter... ) now on Xcode 8 / Swift 3 syntax is cleaner, so no need to add (:_); compiler will find the method.

so the following code works fine:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
}


final func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton){

}
```

if You try to mess compiler, i.e:

```
final func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton. fake: int){..
```

You will be called (as signature is correct..) but the parameter "fake" will get garbage from stack.

Of course:

```
final func buttonTapped(){..
```

works and is called. (no param is taken from stack).

By the way I prefer old syntax that required multiple ":" for every param, as per previous code:

```
"pressed:"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has not problem at all with the number of `UIButton` associated to the same function, you're missing the colon at the end of the selector for the `UIBUtton` as your function receive a parameter in his signature, so you need to change the following line:

```
array[i].addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thats the answer! Give me a sec o mark it though because I have to wait two minutes...

Comment: yup thats basically what i thought it would be

Comment: Yeap, since I see the code I'm waiting for he post the error to answer properly